# C++ multiple process shared memory implementation

Tags: c++, ipc, shared-memory

Here's what I am trying to accomplish.

I want program1 to create a shared memory segment where I store various arrays.

Then, I want program2 to read in the arrays and modify them.

This sounds pretty simple, but for some reason, I cannot find a single example online that shows how this is done. Every example I have found uses a single program (e.g the initialize, read and write are both done by program1).

If somebody can provide an example here, I'm sure this would be hugely beneficial for pretty much everybody that wants to use IPC in C++.

Comment: The *first* Google hit for *"shared memory" + example* (http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22shared+memory%22+example) has a two-process example.

Comment: That article is from 1999, it seems very outdated.

Comment: In what way does it seem outdated?  Have you found any specific problems with it?

Comment: The article probably still works, I'm just wondering whether there is a more modern approach that may have been developed over the last 12 years.

Comment: Understood.  But any library that offers IPC/SHM will essentially be a wrapper on this low-level mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

Boost.Interprocess has a [guide for the impatient](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html).